# Can't access my running instance

Tags: ubuntu, eucalyptus, uec

I can't login to my running instance when I try to connect to it using command:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/eucakey ubuntu@192.168.1.120` (eucakey is the keypair I used to run the image I download the image from store)

the following out appear: 
`Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`

this is the output of `ssh -i ~/.ssh/eucakey -vvv ubuntu@192.168.1.120` :

```
OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config

debug1: Applying options for *

debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0

debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.120 [192.168.1.120] port 22.

debug1: Connection established.

debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier

debug3: Could not load "/home/asraa/.ssh/eucakey" as a RSA1 public key

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'

debug3: key_read: missing keytype

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace

debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'

debug3: key_read: missing keytype

debug1: identity file /home/asraa/.ssh/eucakey type -1

debug1: identity file /home/asraa/.ssh/eucakey-cert type -1

debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3

debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu3 pat OpenSSH*

debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0

debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3

debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.120" from file "/home/asraa/.ssh/known_hosts"

debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/asraa/.ssh/known_hosts:3

debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys

debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.1.120" from file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys

debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa...00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer
```

please help

I am also delete the keypair and generate a new one and use it but still the same problem the same output?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are using the key for euca administration to access instance. You need a different key for that.